# Void attributes are not exported

Tags: gephi

I have encountered some issues when I exported my graph in the format gexf.
My previous structure, which I imported, is a gexf graph. I use Gephi toolkit to spatialize the graph and add node colors. Some attribute values are void. As in this example:

```
<node id="3" label="label_name">
<attvalues>
<attvalue for="1" value="attribute_value" />
<attvalue for="2" value="attribute_value" />
<attvalue for="3" value="1" />
<attvalue for="4" value="" />
<attvalue for="5" value="" />
<attvalue for="6" value="@IP" />
<attvalue for="7" value="" />
<attvalue for="8" value="80" />
```

After spatialization and other actions, I export back to gexf. I noticed attributes which have void values are not included. This is the gexf exported :

```
<node id="3" label="label_name">
<attvalues>
<attvalue for="1" value="attribute_value" />
<attvalue for="2" value="attribute_value" />
<attvalue for="3" value="1" />
<attvalue for="6" value="@IP" />
<attvalue for="8" value="80" />
```

Attributes 4, 5 and 7 are missing. How can I solve this (or is it an implicit action of the Gephi exporter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where does the issue come from. It's in the code of gephi-toolkit, in the class ***ExporterGEXF.java***. Especially in the method ***writeAttValues(XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter, AttributeRow row, TimeInterval visibleInterval)***.

In this method, all nodes are iterated and for each node all attributes are iterated. Next, the current attribute is tested : if it is not null, we write the attribute in the xml file. **If not, the attribute null is ignored.**

I am not going re compil the gephi toolkit, so i will replace all null attributes by a space (string).

I hope it will help...